# Algorithm to rearrange string permutations. How can I solve it?

Tags: algorithm

It's a string algorithm problem, but I don't know how to solve it.
Please try to loosen it once.

### Question

This is a problem of outputting a displayable string by rearranging the input string. (I.e., the problem of printing the permutations of given characters)

For example, in the case of the ab string, there are two possible characters: ab and ba.

A character string is entered, and the characters that can be entered in the character string are numbers, upper/lower case letters, and there may be multiple characters of the same character. (However, when entering a character string, the number of characters constituting the character string (L) can be up to 10 (1≤L≤10)).

All character strings that can be rearranged and displayed are output, and the criteria to be sorted at the time of printing are in alphabetical order of alphabet and number, but uppercase letters in English take precedence over lowercase letters in English, and letters take precedence over numbers.

When a character string is entered, I am thinking about the place to check upper/lower case letters and numbers. Check method must be done in ASCII code.

In the output place, when rearranging is performed, it is necessary to sort in alphabetical order and numerical order, but I am not sure how to code this sorting method with what kind of sorting method.

Lowercase alphabetic characters must take precedence, and alphabetic characters must take precedence over numbers.
Uppercase English letters> Lowercase English letters> Numbers

My shameful code

```java
package example_1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class example1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc.nextLine();

        for(int i =0; i < str.length(); i++) {

            char check = str.charAt(i);
            int iCheck = (int)check;

            boolean strLengthCnk =  1 <= str.length() && str.length() <= 10;
            boolean engSleCnk = 65 <= iCheck && iCheck <= 90;
            boolean engCplCnk = 97 <= iCheck && iCheck <= 122;
            boolean numCnk = 48 <= iCheck && iCheck <= 57;

            if(!strLengthCnk) {
                System.out.println("Out of range of string.");
                return;
            } else if(!(engSleCnk && engSleCnk)) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a english");
            } else if(!numCnk) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a number.");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: 1. Generate all permutations 2. Create a custom sort function. Solutions to both parts can be easily found online

Comment: Does this help? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/ There are also links to other algorithms similar problems in this website.